Spark Block Manager Shuffle File getting deleted during spark execution
I am facing the following error,as the shuffle block gets auto-deleted causing error during ETL job.
I am using spark 3.5.3 - I have checked with multiple different versions including 3.4.3 also, however still getting this error
[2024-10-22T13:45:14.512+0000] {spark_submit.py:634} INFO - 24/10/22 13:45:14 WARN DiskBlockObjectWriter: Error deleting /opt/airflow/logs/temp/blockmgr-956c6232-7f9c-49dd-ab05-edbfcd9a9644/09/temp_shuffle_c82a7379-8206-4c93-a75c-60cc7f889bd1
[2024-10-22T13:45:14.515+0000] {spark_submit.py:634} INFO - 24/10/22 13:45:14 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2598.0 (TID 4663)
[2024-10-22T13:45:14.515+0000] {spark_submit.py:634} INFO - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/airflow/logs/temp/blockmgr-956c6232-7f9c-49dd-ab05-edbfcd9a9644/09/temp_shuffle_c82a7379-8206-4c93-a75c-60cc7f889bd1 (No such file or directory)
[2024-10-22T13:45:14.515+0000] {spark_submit.py:634} INFO - at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
[2024-10-22T13:45:14.515+0000] {spark_submit.py:634} INFO - at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:293)
I tried setting, spark.worker.cleanup.enabled = false, however still facing the same issue.
There is sufficient space in the node i have checked by using both the commands.
df -h
df -i
The block manager folder is there.
Can someone help with this

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am using spark 3.5.3, I want a resolution for the error as the generated shuffle blocks get deleted automatically
